# how to calculate mean of some rows for each given date in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe with 5 columns and 50k rows.all columns are `int` except the `date` that is `date time`.

[image]

In this dataframe, data gathered for 1 year and **there are multiple data for one day**. i want to calculate the mean and variance of some columns for each day and put it in a new data frame.

Is there any pandas function or other way to do this?

Comment: To make your question easier to answer, take the output from `df.to_dict()` or something else and paste it as part of your question. That way we can easily recreate your DataFrame. Pictures of your DataFrame are a lot less helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `groupby`, it will return a new dataframe for you.

```
df.groupby('date').mean()
df.groupby('date').std()
```

isolating columns:

```
df.groupby('date')['price_per_unit'].mean()
```

Comment: how do i exclude some columns in `df.groupby('date').mean()` ?

Comment: `df.groupby('date')['price_per_unit'].mean()` or similar.

Comment: how do i `groupby` by `month` in a `date` column?

Comment: try `df.set_index('date').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M")).mean()`